# How do I use my laptop's media keys with decibel-audio-player?

Tags: sound, music

This is not a question about setting up media keys, as mine have all been recognised and have their correct keysyms assigned, and I can use `rhythmbox` with them and other applications.

I was thinking that there must be a way to use the special XF86Audio keys (such as play, stop, next, and previous track buttons) with `decibel`, as most media player applications 'grab' the keys when you start the application. Some need setting up manually, but there doesn't seem to be any guides for `decibel-audio-player`.

Is it possible to use the appropriate laptop media keys with this player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your multimedia keys have been recognised and have their appropriate keysym assigned, the following explanation will work fine. If not, please see [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys) and my answer [for this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179556/how-do-i-get-the-media-keys-on-an-asus-k53br-working).

Your 'XF86Audio' media keys (i.e. play, pause, next track, previous track buttons) usually do not work straightaway with `decibel-audio-player`, so you need to use the remote application, which is by default located at `/usr/share/decibel-audio-player/src/remote.py`. To find the valid options, just run it with python:

```
python /usr/share/decibel-audio-player/src/remote.py
```

Here is the full list of options available for the command-line application, `remote.py`:

```
Command  | Arguments        | Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
next     |                  | Jump to the next track
pause    |                  | Pause or continue playing the current track
pl-add   | file1 file2...   | Append the given files to the playlist
pl-clr   |                  | Clear the playlist
pl-set   | file1 file2...   | Set the playlist to the given files
play     |                  | Start playing the current track
prev     |                  | Jump to the previous track
shuffle  |                  | Shuffle the playlist
stop     |                  | Stop playback
volume   | value (0 -- 100) | Set the volume
```

So, from the command-line, the python command that pause/plays a track when `decibel-audio-player` is already running is:

```
python /usr/share/decibel-audio-player/src/remote.py pause
```

Other commands that can be assigned to media buttons (individually) are, for example:

```
python /usr/share/decibel-audio-player/src/remote.py stop
python /usr/share/decibel-audio-player/src/remote.py next
python /usr/share/decibel-audio-player/src/remote.py prev
```

Now all you need to do is to assign the appropriate python command to the XF86 keysym that represents, for example, your play/pause on your laptop. Do this by going to shortcut settings, adding a new keyboard shortcut, then placing in the box the appropriate line above and then pressing the appropriate media key.

[image]

Repeat this method for however many media keys you have by using a different command and different media key every time.

When you have finished, your keyboard shortcuts application will look something like this, although I am using Xfce, so the settings section will look different for other desktop environments:

[image]

I thought this information was worth sharing, as I haven't been able to find any similar tutorials elsewhere, so perhaps it will be useful for someone.